# Creating .exe using Lauch4j and jLink from .jar

Tags: java, maven, exe, launch4j

I am trying create independent on machine java version .exe from .jar using maven.
For packaging .jar using maven-assembly-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <outputDirectory>target\jar-with-dependencies</outputDirectory>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.ge.Sample</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then for creating java image I using exec-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jlink</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>jlink</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jre-image</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--no-header-files</argument>
                            <argument>--strip-debug</argument>
                            <argument>--no-man-pages</argument>
                            <argument>--compress=2</argument>
                            <argument>--add-modules</argument>
                            <argument>java.base,java.compiler,java.datatransfer,java.desktop,java.logging,java.management,java.naming,java.rmi,java.security.sasl,java.sql,java.xml</argument>
                            <argument>--output</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/jre</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And on the end, for creating .exe using launch4j plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-clui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>console</headerType>
                        <outfile>target\application\Sample.exe</outfile>
                        <jar>target\jar-with-dependencies\Sample-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                        <errTitle>encc</errTitle>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>com.ge.Sample</mainClass>
                            <preCp>target\jre\lib\*</preCp>
                        </classPath>
                        <jre>
                            <path>target\jre</path>
                            <minVersion>17.0.6</minVersion>
                            <requiresJdk>true</requiresJdk>
                            <initialHeapSize>256</initialHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>0.0.0.1</fileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>a description</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>Company</copyright>
                            <productVersion>0.0.0.1</productVersion>
                            <productName>E-N-C-C</productName>
                            <internalName>ccne</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>original.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

With this configuration, I can create .exe but it is still dependent on java in machine.
Can you give me a advice for creating .exe dependent only on jLink created java image?

Comment: Sorry but there is no such thing as a machine independent `.exe` file.

Comment: @StephenC I mean, that you can run Sample.exe on machine without java